# Where I can locate the iOS app executable .ipa file on my MacBook to share to mdm for distribution?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4.2

I done the build for iOS app and want to know where the .ipa executable is created?

I done a small change and want to send the executable to MDM for distribution.

Comment: When you generate the IPA via Xcode, you will select the path you saved...

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Open the project in **Xcode**
2. **Product - Archiv**e
3. When the archives are displayed select **Distribute app**
   [image]
4. Select **iOS App Store**
5. **Export** (this will generate the desired ipa file)
   [image]
6. The ipa can be uploaded to appstore connect via **Application Loader** on mac
   [image]